# Regional block for website domain?

Tags: domain, blocking

Im administrating a website and someone pointed out to me that they can't access the site from any of their devices or browsers. It says "this webpage is not available", and tells him to check his connection etc etc whenever he tries. I have tested it on several of my own devices and it works just fine. This person lives in America whilst I live in Norway, so I got to thinking that maybe his country doesnt allow .cf urls? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ask for a traceroute from the US visitor to the website you're administrating to see what's going on. If no interruption occurs in the hops to your domain you're likely to be having filtering issues from your own hosting company for some reason, or something alike.
You could also ask your US visitor to try to access your website through a US proxy: if this way they can reach your website your problem is related to its location or IP address (so it's a user-specific issue). Helpful info.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. He was able to access the page when using a vpn. So you think the problem is with his home network then? He said he tried it with his computer and cellphone, but they were probably both connected to the same wifi. He also tried going to www.dot.cf to see if it was a bock on the domain extension, but he had no problems accessing that site. This is starting to make less and less sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a ".cf" url is, but that is unlikely to be your problem - if the site says "this webpage is not available", the problem is a connectivity problem between him and you.  Can other people in Norway see your site ?

Comment: Yes it works all devices I have tested, and on different networks. I know for a fact it works in Germany and some middle-eastern country, and a few others. .cf is just the url extension (like .com). It's from a free hosting service so they are often used for illegal websites, which led me to believe they have blocked it.

Comment: If you're familiar with .co.cc, .cf is basically the same thing, a free TLD

Comment: As someone in the ISP business I can say that it is unlikely that the domain name would be blocked throughout the USA - it is possible (but unlikely) that his ISP blocked it.    I do note that the ".cf" namespace is available in NZ and from Googles nameservers.